# C++ conversion between char and int with wrong result

Tags: c++, string

i want to convert between char and int in c++ but i've found a problem with char to int conversion.

I did a test with two numbers, 103 and 155. 103 give me "g" in char and 155 give me "ø" and both are correct, but the problem is when i try to back chars to int: "g" give me 103 (correct) but i don't know why "ø" give me -101.

I'm using a char variable to store numbers, and "prinf("%d", char[x]);" to show back the number.

I've this test script:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int numero = 26523;    

char *inttochar(int number) {
    char *salida;
    for (int j=0;j<=5;j++) {
        salida[5-j] = number % 256;
        printf("%d = %d = %c = %c = %d\n", 5-j, number % 256, number % 256, salida[5-j], salida[5-j]);
        number = number / 256;
    }
    return salida;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *texto = inttochar(numero);

    for (int j=0;j<=5;j++) {
        printf("%d: ", j+1);
        printf("%c = %d\n", texto[j], texto[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And result is:

```
5 = 155 = ø = ø = -101
4 = 103 = g = g = 103
3 = 0 =   =   = 0
2 = 0 =   =   = 0
1 = 0 =   =   = 0
0 = 0 =   =   = 0
1:   = 0
2:   = 0
3:   = 0
4:   = 0
5: g = 103
6: ø = -101
```

With this script i want to convert a number to a base 256 char. ¿What i'm doing wrong?.

Thanks!!, and i'm sorry for my english.

Comment: It's implementation defined whether `char` is a signed or unsigned type. It's signed on your platform.

Comment: Note also that `char *salida;` is a wild pointer, so pretty much anything can happen...

Comment: Why the heck are you `using namespace std;`? I don't even really see any `c++` code here.

Comment: Just use `std::to_string` and be done with it.

Comment: I'm new in c++, and i'm trying to learn. Is an experiment and i know that some things are wrong and unnecessary. "using namespace std;" is a line added by Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters are signed values between -128 and 127 (on most systems). You're converting something from outside that range; the conversion to a `char` truncates but the bit pattern is OK. Converting the other direction puts you back into the range, and 155 isn't part of it. The bit pattern for 155 is 0x9b; to convert to a signed value you invert the bits and add one, so it becomes -0x65 which is -101 in decimal.

You can fix it with an `and` that strips off the extended sign bits: `salida[5-j] & 0xff`.

Edit: As noted in the comments your `salida` variable is intended to be a string but you never allocate any storage for it.

```
char *salida = new char[6];
```

Comment: It might help to allocate some valid memory for `salida` first.

Comment: @PaulR good point, I hadn't noticed that. But I think you're telling the wrong person...

Comment: I thought you might like to add this to your answer, since you've already covered the main point.

Comment: @PaulR, oops I almost compounded that mistake before I noticed that `salida` is being returned from the function. I hope I fixed that before anybody noticed.

Comment: Just worked like a charm, thank you very much. I've read something about c++ and variables, but nothing about char values. I thought that char are between 0 and 255, and now i know that isn't ;)

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín, the standard leaves it up to the implementation whether `char` is signed or unsigned. Most use signed due to historical precedence, which is unfortunate; unsigned works better most of the time.

Comment: Ad edit: I'd go one step further and very strongly suggest it should be a `std::string` instead. This is C++.

Answer (score 0):

`char` appears to be a signed type on your platform.  That means `155` won't fit in it.  You're getting that `155` interpreted as a 2's complement signed number, which equals `-101`.